# Replacing main branch by another on Github

Tags: git, github

I'm currently an owner of a project on Github.
Actually, I have many branches: V4, V5, V7 (currently in dev) and **final**.

The **final** branch is actually the equivalent of the v6 branch (which does not yet exists).

My current concern is that I'm about to release the v7 and merge it to the **final** branch just **after** creating the v6 branch from **final** and I don't how the releases will react if i remote the **final** branch and replace it with a **master** one.

The choice to call it **final** was due to my predecessor and to be compliant with modern git conventions I want to call my Master branch... **master**

But does this will delete/affect my releases that were based on the **final** branch even if the commits will just be kind of "transfered" to the **master** branch ?

Here's the [concerned project](https://github.com/PHPSocialNetwork/phpfastcache).

Comment: To clarify, you're worried about the history of other branches if you rename a branch they were based off of? The answer then is no. Github doesn't actually track branches, it only tracks commits. You can go crazy renaming stuff and as long as the commit history is the same nothing changes

Comment: Almost that, I'm worried that if I remove the final branch this affect my releases. I'm not worried about other branch history.

Comment: removing branches does nothing to existing tags or other branches

Comment: this is also super easy to test.. just make a new repo.. make a release from a branch then delete it and see what happens for yourself

Comment: You took that doubt away from me, I wanna be sure before doing something potentially crazy or stupid.

Comment: just make sure you have the history locally too in case you mess something up.. can always just resync from local, or even a fork for that matter

Comment: Sure I do actually, with multiple backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Releases** in github are just pointers to **tags**, which you can think of as branches. Deleting a branch does not affect any other branch or tag. Each branch or tag in git is just a string of commits, and as long as that string exists, or is a subset of commits in a different branch then the history is saved, and new tags can be made with that history.

When in doubt, fork the repo and make "scary" changes and see what happens in the fork.